# Derivative of $a^x$ for $a<0$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, exponential-function

Is it correct to write that
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( a^x \right)
 = a^x \log(a) $$
also for $a < 0$, where $\log$ is the natural logarithm?

I was trying to compute the derivative of $(-10)^x$. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+(-10)%5Ex) gave the following result:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \bigl( (-10)^x \bigr)
 = (-10)^x (\log(10) + \mathrm{i}\pi),$$
but I am not sure if it is correct, because in this case the argument of logarithm is negative.

The reason why I am asking this question is becasue I want to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A}+|C_3|^{A}-|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A}}{a^xD_1+(ka)^xD_2}$$

knowing that $-1<a<1$, $-1<k<1$, $1<A<2$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since for $x \to \infty$ we have $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$, I use the de L'Hopital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A}+|C_3|^{A}-|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A}}{a^xD_1+(ka)^xD_2}=\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A-1}sgn(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x)(C_1a^xlog(a)+C_2(ka)^xlog(ka)) ...}{a^xlog(a)D_1+(ka)^xlog(ka)D_2}\\\frac{-A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A-1}sgn(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3)(C_1a^xlog(a)+C_2(ka)^xlog(ka))}{a^xlog(a)D_1+(ka)^xlog(ka)D_2}$$

Now, I take the expression $a^x$ in front of both nominator and denominator and reduce it obtaining

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A-1}sgn(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x)(C_1log(a)+C_2(k)^xlog(ka)) ...}{log(a)D_1+(k)^xlog(ka)D_2}\\\frac{-A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A-1}sgn(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3)(C_1log(a)+C_2(k)^xlog(ka))}{log(a)D_1+(k)^xlog(ka)D_2}$$

and finally I obtain $\frac{A|C_3|^{A-1}sgn(C_3)C_1log(a)}{log(a)D_1}$ as the result.

At some point, I calculate the derivative of $a^x$ which is equal to $a^xlog(a)$ and I am sure that it is correct in the case of $0<a<1$, but what if $-1<a<0$? Can I write that the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^xlog(a)$ when $-1<a<0$? If not, how should I calculate this limit in the case of $-1<a<0$?

Comment: For $a<0$, there isn't even an obvious way to *define* that function, let alone compute its derivative.

Comment: It would help a potential answer-writer give you a useful answer if you explained your motivation for asking this. The short answer is that (1) there is a way to make sense of the identity that makes it true (by regarding it as a complex-valued function), but (2) given what little context there is in the question it doesn't seem like that's what you want, and (3) even then there are issues about what one means by $a^x$ for $a$ not a positive real number.

Comment: "In this case the argument of logarithm is negative." Note that Wolfram Alpha already told you that $\log(-10) = \log(10) + \mathrm{i} \pi$.

Comment: Thank you. Now, I explained my motivation - the question is edited.

Comment: The edit fails to address all the concerns. For example, you seem to think that $C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x$ has a sign, when either $a$ or $ka$ may be negative?

Comment: Jyrki Lahtonen, I am not sure what you mean. Can you explain me your question?

Comment: Let's consider $a=-1/2$. Then by the usual conventions
$$a^x=\frac1{2^x}\left(\cos((2n+1)x\pi)+i\sin((2n+1)x\pi)\right)$$ for all integers $n$. Simultaneously (unless you specify a branch). Let's further pick $x=1/4$. What is the sign of 
$$\frac1{\root4\of2}\left(\cos(n\pi/2+\frac\pi4)+i\sin(n\pi/2+\pi/4)\right)?$$

Comment: I should write that $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So, as far as I understand you I cannot calculate the derivative in this way when $a<0$.

Comment: @Gatey, if you restrict the domain of $a^x$ to $x\in\mathbb{N}$, you can no longer define a derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Of course $a^x$ where $a<0$ and $x$ is irrational is a complex number, not a real number.  So let us define
$$
\mathrm{Log}\; a
$$
to be the **principal value** of the multivalued function $\log a$; that is the solution $z$ of $e^z=a$ with argument in $(-\pi,\pi]$.  Then define
$$
a^x = \exp(x\;\mathrm{Log}\;a)
$$

So, when $a$ is real and negative, we have $\mathrm{Log}\;a = \log|a|+i\pi$ and
$$
a^x = \exp(x\;\mathrm{Log}\;a) = \exp(x\; (\log|a|+i\pi))
=e^{x\log|a|}\; e^{i\pi x} = |a|^x\;\big(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)\big)
$$

Now we are in a position to consider the derivative formula.

Use the product rule,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big(a^x\big) = |a|^x\;\big(-\pi\sin(\pi x)+i \pi \cos(\pi x)\big)
+|a|^x\;\log|a|\;\big(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)\big)
$$
and on the other hand
\begin{align}
a^x\;\mathrm{Log}\;a &= 
|a|^x\;\big(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)\big)\;\big(\log|a|+i\pi\big)
\\
&=|a|^x\;\big(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)\big)\;\big(\log|a|\big)
+|a|^x\;\big(\cos(\pi x)+i\sin(\pi x)\big)\;\big(i\pi\big)
\end{align}
They agree.